# what's the best practice in PHP?

Tags: php

I would like the experts to give me some suggestions in organizing my code in PHP. Usually what i do is that i break the code into multiple files, and then `include();` them all into a master file. this makes it easier for me to debug the code but the program gets slow. So, masters of programming, please suggest me something.

Comment: Using an autoloader rather than all those manual includes would certainly make things easier for you

Comment: @mark - can you please provide me with an example code snippet for better understanding?

Comment: Could you post some of your code? That would be easier to give you some advice.

Comment: @michiel - `<?php include('codesegment1.php'); include('codesegment2.php'); ?>` here i include the two files containing code snippets of the whole program. now for eg in codesegment1.php: `<?php echo "hello"; ?>`. And in codesegment2.php:  `<?php echo "hello"; ?>`

Comment: Probably a first question would be whether you code procedurally, or use OOP. If the former, then you would probably just execute a directory loop and load each file returned by (for example) glob(). If the latter, then the spl_autoloader (link in Industrial's reply) to automatically include class files when they are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [Autoload PHP5 OOP Manual Page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

you can see that an Autoloader can be "crawl" into directories for "find out" classes.

you can set it up (as suggested, and as in MVC like Zend happend) for crawl directory creating classes like Connector.class.php that is placed into site/DB/ folder and called as: new DB_Connector()

Answer (score 1):

A pretty big question and i'm sure people prefer different things. Generally speaking, there is an index page where pages are included on request (most times using a switch for file inclusion attack prevention).

The included pages also have a defined constant that is checked, in order to make sure that they cannot be executed individually.

I always prefer to use a template system (a php one actually, a very very fast one) and i organize my code using an MVC type(model view controller). I create a user.php, a user.class.php and the user templates, for instance(user is the controller, class is the model, templates the view).

EDIT - An example of an index page from an old project (cut down to just show the points)
In this one i was using Smarty, btw.

```
<?php
define('game',1);

session_start();

require_once 'libs/smartySetup.php';
require_once 'libs/containers/utils.class.php';
require_once 'login.php';

$page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 'home';
$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';

switch($page)
{
    case 'home':       break;    // unlogged 
    case 'register':   break;    // unlogged
    case 'town':       break;
    default:
        $page = 'home';
}

include("$page.php");


?>
```

Comment: sir, as i am still a learner in programming, can you please edit your answer and give some illustrations and coding snippets for my help. hope you dont mind.

Comment: I'm pasting an example index page from an old project of mine.

Comment: ohk, thanks for the code. it was useful.

Comment: notice that the included pages, like town.php must start with "if (!defined('game')) die('Access Denied');" for security purposes.

Comment: "*The included pages also have a defined constant that is checked, in order to make sure that they cannot be executed individually*" - I would suggest to only define classes in non-index files, 1 class per file. That's the only code that should be in non-index files. Exception is config file, which would set up environment for whole system - set constants, error reporting, timezone etc. That would make code more "structural". It also would mean that the code has to be somehow "triggered" from index file to actually do something, so there would be no threat of executing individually.

Comment: As i said, i do define classes in files like user.class.php :) However, user.php is a controller and does not only have classes but some other initialization stuff as well. That is why is use guards on these files. The classes files, of course, do not need such guards.

Answer (score 1):

As for the comments on Autoloaders: http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php